# TikZ: Named nodes in nested `pic`s

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the new TikZ/PGF 3.0 `pic` feature.  I use them heavily, including using a pic inside another pic.  The problem is that Tikz sometimes cannot find the node names of nested pics.

I expect the following to work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{complex/.pic={
  \node(re) {re};
  \node[right=0mm of re](im) {im};
}}
\tikzset{su3v/.pic={
  \path pic(c0) {complex};
  \path pic[right=1mm of c0im](c1) {complex};
  \path pic[right=1mm of c1im](c2) {complex};
}}
\tikzset{spinor/.pic={
  \path pic(v0) {su3v};
  \path pic[below=2mm of v0c2re](v1) {su3v};
  \path pic[below=2mm of v1c2re](v2) {su3v};
  \path pic[below=2mm of v2c2re](v3) {su3v};
}}

\path pic {su3v};       % Works
\path pic(name) {su3v}; % ! Package pgf Error: No shape named namec0im is known.
\path pic {spinor};     % ! Package pgf Error: No shape named v0c1im is known.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: `name prefix ..` could be a clue here. For the first level, it seems to work: `\tikzset{su3v/.pic={\path pic(c0) {complex};\path pic[name prefix ..,right=1mm of c0im](c1) {complex};\path pic[name prefix ..,right=1mm of c1im](c2) {complex};}}`.

Comment: Interesting; I wasn't aware of `name prefix ..`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going for **bug** on this one.

When drawing a `pic`, it is possible to use subnodes (and coordinates).  If the outer `pic` is given a name then that name is passed on to all subnodes (and coordinates) as a prefix.  This is a Good Thing as it means you don't risk name clash.  You're nesting `pic`s, so the names ought to accumulate.  We can draw the nesting and naming as a tree, illustrating what **ought** to happen.  The `name` is the name of the current `pic`, and the `prefix` is the assigned prefix for all *sub* pics.

```
pic {su3v};                    <no prefix>   <no name>
 |
 -- pic (c0) {complex}          c0            c0
     |
     -- node (re) {re}                        c0re
     -- node (im) {im}                        c0im

pic (name) {su3v};              name          name
 |
 -- pic (c0) {complex}          namec0        namec0
     |
     -- node (re) {re}                        namec0re
     -- node (im) {im}                        namec0im

pic {spinor};                  <no prefix>   <no name>
 |
 -- pic (v0) {su3v}             v0            v0
     |
     -- pic (c0) {complex}      v0c0          v0c0
         |
         -- node (re) {re}                    v0c0re
         -- node (im) {im}                    v0c0im
```

(For those to whom this is new, the idea is that to refer to nodes, we use the full name minus the current prefix.  So inside `su3v` we can refer to `c0im` and `c1im` as you do, even when `su3v` is named or is used inside `spinor`.)

Now, I said that this is what **ought** to happen.  It doesn't.  What actually happens is that when a `pic` starts then the `name prefix` has the **current full name** set as *its* prefix.  That is to say, the `name prefix` itself has a prefix and said prefix is the *full* name of the current `pic`.  The key is that that name has *already* had its own prefix appended.

So when nesting `pic`s, the following happens.  The first named `pic`, let's call it `outer`, sets the prefix of `name prefix` to its name, in this case `outer`.  So whenever `name prefix` is called, `outer` is prefixed to its value.  Inside `outer`, let's have another `pic`, say `inner`.  As this is inside `outer`, its real name is `outerinner`.  The `name prefix`'s prefix is set to this, but `name prefix` itself retains its value of `outer`.  Thus the effective `name prefix` is `outerinnerouter`.  Thus the *actual* tree is as follows:

```
pic {su3v};                    <no prefix>   <no name>
 |
 -- pic (c0) {complex}          c0            c0
     |
     -- node (re) {re}                        c0re
     -- node (im) {im}                        c0im

pic (name) {su3v};              name          name
 |
 -- pic (c0) {complex}          namec0name    namec0
     |
     -- node (re) {re}                        namec0namere
     -- node (im) {im}                        namec0nameim

pic {spinor};                  <no prefix>   <no name>
 |
 -- pic (v0) {su3v}             v0            v0
     |
     -- pic (c0) {complex}      v0c0v0        v0c0
         |
         -- node (re) {re}                    v0c0v0re
         -- node (im) {im}                    v0c0v0im
```

I should mention a useful diagnostic at this point.  This is to put the following in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{show fig name/.code={\tikz@addmode{\message{Fig name is: |\tikz@fig@name|}}}}
\makeatother
```

and then use the key `show fig name` on various elements.

I guess that the point of this is that if you *manually* set `name prefix` then you want to preserve that and to append all of the automatic prefixes.  If you never do this, one fix is to copy the code for `\def\tikz@subpicture@handle@` into your preamble (between the obligatory `\makeatletter .. \makeatother` pairing) and change

```
  \ifx\tikz@fig@name\pgfutil@empty\else%
    \tikzset{name prefix/.prefix/.expanded=\tikz@fig@name}%
  \fi%
```

to

```
  \ifx\tikz@fig@name\pgfutil@empty\else%
    \tikzset{name prefix/.expanded=\tikz@fig@name}%
  \fi%
```

A better solution would be that instead of using `\tikz@fig@name`, then it used the *declared* name (which isn't currently saved - the prefix and suffix are added when the node/pic/coordinate is first named) and added it as a *suffix* to the *prefix* to `name prefix`.  That is to say, the crucial line might be:

```
\tikzset{name prefix/.prefix/.suffix/.expanded=\tikz@fig@declaredname}
```

and the `name` key would have to become:

```
\tikzset{
  name/.code={\edef\tikz@fig@name{\tikz@pp@name{#1}}\edef\tikz@fig@declaredname{#1}}%
 }
```

Unfortunately, nesting `/.prefix/.suffix` doesn't work so a proper fix will have to wait for the PGF people to figure out what would be a good solution.  In the meantime, if you never call `name prefix` itself then modifying `\tikz@subpicture@handle@` seems to work.

No guarantees, though.

---

Actually, I just thought of an alternative fix.  That is to *set* `name prefix/.prefix` to `\tikz@fig@name` as the original code does, but then to clear `name prefix` itself since whatever the current `name prefix` is, it has been taken into account in `\tikz@fig@name`.  Further calls to `name prefix` will keep the prefix to `name prefix` as intended.

Also, I've [filed this on the PGF bug list](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/312/) with a link back here.

Comment: The `\def\tikz@subpicture@handle@` solution works as I wasn't even aware of the `name prefix` key. Thanks for the extensive answer and filing the bug.

Comment: `\tikzset{name prefix/.expanded=\tikz@fig@name}` seems to work fine.  I haven't found any case yet where this breaks.

Comment: If this works, this will be in PGF 3.1.5. https://github.com/hmenke/pgf/commit/88951be592b558b94b14a97aaffe9df6c1ce61ee