# A nice example with `name prefix ..`

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

`TiKZ pics` include a new key called `name prefix ..`. `TiKZ` documentation defines it with

> `/tikz/name prefix ..`
>
> This key is available only inside the
>   code of a pic. There, it (locally) changes the name prefix to the
>   value it had outside the pic. This allows you to access nodes outside
>   the current pic.

but it doesn't show any example. In TeX.SX I've just found [JLDiaz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12571/jldiaz) [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184113/1952) to  [Nodes and matrix of nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183896/nodes-and-matrix-of-nodes/184113#184113) where I don't understand what `name prefix ..` is used for. So, could you write a more simple example of its use?

Comment: When your document has these name prefixes, you can for instance draw an arrow between the two pictures, even if you used seperate `figure` environments for them.

Comment: @1010011010 I understand what `name prefix` does within an scope. There are some example in pgfmanual. But not whithin a `pic` where is key `name prefix ..` (with `..` not just `name prefix`) defined.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176900/15925

Comment: When the code inside a `pic` refers to any node name, tikz automatically inserts before it a prefix (which is given where the pic is used). For example, `\path (0,0) pic (foo) {bar};` inserts the pic defined by `bar/.pic`, using `foo` as prefix. Whenever inside the code of that pic you refer to node `(X)`, tikz indeed interprets `(fooX)`, since the prefix is automatically prepended. `name prefix ..` avoids that, so allows you to access to nodes defined in the main pic. Read the  `..` as in the unix commmand `cd ..`

Comment: In [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184113/12571) you refer to, it was neccessary to add this in the node which used a shadow, because internally tikz refers to the node `(current bounding box)` for computing the shadow, and without `name prefix ..` option, an error appears about `unknown node (foocurrent bounding box)` (being `foo` the name prefix in this example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an extension of the example used in the [PGF documentation](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) about pics, I propose to draw coconuts, and attach them to seagulls (as we are lacking swallows).

We will use the `seagull` pic defined in the manual, and introduce another very simple pic called `coconut`, but we want to ensure that each coconut is attached to a seagull.

Here is the definition of both pics:

```
\tikzset{
    seagull/.pic={
        % Code for a "seagull". Do you see it?...
        \coordinate (-left wing) at (-3mm,0);
        \coordinate (-head) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (-right wing) at (3mm,0);

        \draw (-3mm,0) to [bend left] (0,0) to [bend left] (3mm,0);
    },
    coconut/.pic={
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=2mm];
        \draw[name prefix ..,very thin] (0,2mm) -- (#1-head)  .. controls ++(-2mm,-0.3mm) and ++(0,-2mm) .. (#1-head) .. controls ++(2mm,-1mm) and ++(0,-2mm) .. (#1-head);
    }
}
```

Notice that we used the key `name prefix ..` in the `draw` call for the coconut, and that a parameter is needed to tell the coconut to which seagull it is attached.
Let's try to use these pics:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic (Veronique) at (0.5,1) {seagull};
    \pic (Virginie) at (-1,0.7) {seagull};
    \pic (Emma) at (0,0) {seagull};
    \pic (Coco) at (0.1,-1) {coconut=Emma};
    \pic (Nut) at (-1.1,-0.8) {coconut=Virginie};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which gives the result:

[image: Seagulls and coconuts]