# Naming pic just like I can name nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to name a pic just like I can name a node in tikz?

I have tried

```
\pic (A) {man};
\pic [right=of A] (B) {man};
```

but it gives me the warning `Package pgf Error: No shape named A is known.`

Comment: No, that's exactly what a `pic` is not able to do. However, if there are nodes inside a pic, these can be referenced by `<pic name>-<node name>`. Check the last two pages of the section on pics in the PGFmanual. Related: [Q176900](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176900), [Q185285](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185285), [Q194362](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194362), [Q241719](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241719); especially the latter.

Comment: The method with the node names inside the `pic` is shown in the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249596/16967) to one of your questions, two days earlier.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Is that working again? Something broke it before... :(.