# Draw a shark with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want draw a simple shark.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=#1] (1,1) to[bend left=50] (3,1) to[bend left=50] 
    (1,1);
    \draw[fill=#1] (3,1) -- (3.5,1.5) -- (3.3,1) -- (3.5,.5) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=white] (1.6,1.1) circle (.15cm); 
    \draw[fill=#1] (1.55,1.1) circle (.05cm);         
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: You were using this terminology before. What precisely do you mean by "using only the library tikz". Does it mean that you don't want to load any Ti*k*Z libraries? (Ti*k*Z itself is a package, which has a lot of libraries that one can load.)

Comment: The drawings are for math exercises. That loads a program that only has tikz and I can not load more packages.

Comment: \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc} or \usepackage{tikz-3dplot} fails

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what you mean by that? That is, you may want to post a new question where you describe what you tried and which error messages you get. I am very confident that someone will be able to help.

Comment: ooh we ducks are afraid of sharks!

Comment: On a more serious note, if the linked question is not exactly what you are trying to achieve, we are more than happy to reopen this thread. Also, you can poke us in the chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends

Comment: @PauloCereda There's now a shark hiding in the OP's fruit bowl, so be careful.

Comment: @cfr oh no, naughty fruit sharks!

Comment: For a shark see Mark Wibrow's answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413389/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-of-an-apple-using-only-the-tikz-library/413395#413395