# There is some program to draw simple objects and get the code in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have to do many math exercises for young children. A drawing helps them a lot. But I can not paste images because it consumes a lot of memory of the [program](http://www.geb.uma.es/projects/toolbox/) that I use so I have to put the pictures in code. Do you know any program that can help me draw?

Comment: [Maybe this is what you're looking for](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz)

Comment: Also related: http://www.texample.net/tikz/resources/ (section `Tools for working with TikZ code` and `Tools that generate PGF/TikZ code`)

Comment: @Zarko I think she really does not want to load any tikz library, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413544/draw-a-shark-with-tikz).

Comment: Sometimes I'm wondering if there is an application with button GetTikZCodeFromTeX.SE, which just posts the picture here and asks "how can I draw this with Ti*k*Z?" ;-)

Comment: If you use something like Inkscape, at least, it will just give you Ti*k*Z code. It won't be pretty, but it won't rely on a lot of extra stuff. (Obviously, things like `xcolor`, because it requires that, but if you can use Ti*k*Z, you already are loading `xcolor`, `graphicx` etc.) In addition, you can download clip art from openclipart.org in SVG format, load it into Inkscape and export Ti*k*Z code. Just do your editing in Inkscape as the code is generally unreadable.

Comment: You can also find some stuff on the Ti*k*Z example site and, of course, here. Much won't be suitable, but quite a lot of cute animals are available: fish, donkeys, pigs, turtles/tortoises, cats, turkeys and, of course, ducks. There are also trams/buses, cars, people, witches, pumkins, presents, trees etc.

Comment: My comment was not specific to you. You show some effort and people (and ducks and marmot) in this forum are eager to help anyway. Your first link, unfortunately, does work since it is private. In any case, I really think you may want to talk to your system administrator to also allow for Ti*k*Z libraries. (And if that does not work, you can always compile on a private computer, on which you install TeXLive or a another bundle.)

Comment: You can also consider using symbols from fonts. There are quite a lot of picture-like glyphs available, even if you cannot use Xe/LuaTeX. `texdoc comprehensive` shows most of them. Fonts for typesetting ancient languages are especially helpful as they have pictorial characters.