# Drawing some fruits with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am lacking these fruits:

[image]
[image]
[image]

MWE from [Mark Wibrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413506/185467)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor-material}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{%
   apple/.pic={
\fill [MaterialBrown] (-1/8,0) 
  arc (180:120:1 and 3/2) coordinate [pos=3/5] (@)-- ++(1/6,-1/7) 
  arc (120:180:5/4 and 3/2) -- cycle;
\fill [MaterialLightGreen500] (0,-9/10) 
  .. controls ++(180:1/8) and ++(  0:1/4) .. (-1/3,  -1)
  .. controls ++(180:1/3) and ++(270:1/2) .. (  -1,   0)
  .. controls ++( 90:1/3) and ++(180:1/3) .. (-1/2, 3/4)
  .. controls ++(  0:1/8) and ++(135:1/8) .. (   0, 4/7)
  .. controls ++( 45:1/8) and ++(180:1/8) .. ( 1/2, 3/4)
  .. controls ++(  0:1/3) and ++( 90:1/3) .. (   1,   0)
  .. controls ++(270:1/2) and ++(  0:1/3) .. ( 1/3,  -1)
  .. controls ++(180:1/4) and ++(  0:1/8) .. cycle;
\fill [MaterialLightGreen600] (0, 4/7)
  .. controls ++( 45:1/8) and ++(180:1/8) .. ( 1/2, 3/4)
  .. controls ++(  0:1/3) and ++( 90:1/3) .. (   1,   0)
  .. controls ++(270:1/2) and ++(  0:1/3) .. ( 1/3,  -1)
  .. controls ++(180:1/4) and ++(  0:1/8) .. (   0,-9/10);
\fill [MaterialGreen500, shift={(@)}, rotate=-30] 
  (0,0) arc (45:135:3/4 and 3/5) arc (225:315:3/4 and 3/5);
\fill [MaterialGreen700, shift={(@)}, rotate=-30] 
  (0,0) arc (315:225:3/4 and 3/5) -- cycle;
},
  orange/.pic={
\fill [MaterialOrange500] (0,0) circle [radius=1];
\fill [MaterialOrange600] (0,0) -- (45:1) arc (45:-135:1) -- cycle;
\fill [MaterialOrange700, shift={(0,3/4)}] coordinate (@)
ellipse [x radius=1/4, y radius=1/8];
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) circle [radius=1];
\fill [MaterialOrange700, shift=(@)] (90:1/4 and 1/8) 
  \foreach \i [evaluate={\j=mod(\i,2)+1/4;}]in {0,...,12}{
  -- (90+\i*30:\j*3/4 and \j*3/8) } -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\fill [MaterialBrown] (-1/16, 3/4) -- ++(0,1/4) arc (180:0:1/16 and 1/32)
   -- ++(0,-1/4) arc (360:180:1/16 and 1/32) -- cycle;
\fill [MaterialGreen500, shift=(@), rotate=-150] 
  (0,0) arc (45:135:1/2 and 4/5) arc (225:315:1/2 and 3/5);
\fill [MaterialGreen700, shift=(@), rotate=-150] 
  (0,0) arc (45:135:1/2 and 4/5) -- cycle;
},
lemon/.pic={
\tikzset{rotate=-45}
\fill [MaterialYellow500] (0, 0) ellipse [x radius=1/3, y radius=  1];
\fill [MaterialYellow500] (0, 0) ellipse [x radius=3/4, y radius=7/8];
\fill [MaterialYellow600] (270:1/3 and   1) arc (270:450:1/3 and   1);
\fill [MaterialYellow600] (270:3/4 and 7/8) arc (270:450:3/4 and 7/8);
\begin{scope}[shift=(90:9/10), rotate=-135]
\fill [MaterialGreen500] 
  (0,0) arc (45:135:1/2 and 4/5) arc (225:315:1/2 and 3/5);
\fill [MaterialGreen700] 
  (0,0) arc (45:135:1/2 and 4/5) -- cycle;
\tikzset{rotate=90, scale=3/4}
\fill [MaterialGreen500] 
  (0,0) arc (45:135:1/2 and 4/5) arc (225:315:1/2 and 3/5);
\fill [MaterialGreen700] 
  (0,0) arc (45:135:1/2 and 4/5) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
},
cherry/.pic={
\foreach \i in {1,2}{
\tikzset{shift={(-1+\i*3/4, -3/5+\i/5)},scale=1/2, rotate=15-\i*10}
\fill [MaterialRed700] (0,19/20) 
  .. controls ++(180:1/8) and ++(  0:1/4) .. (-1/3,  1)
  .. controls ++(180:1/3) and ++( 90:1/2) .. (  -1,  0)
  .. controls ++(270:1/2) and ++(180:1/2) .. (   0, -1)
  .. controls ++(  0:1/2) and ++(270:1/2) .. (   1,  0)
  .. controls ++( 90:1/2) and ++(  0:1/3) .. ( 1/3,  1)
  .. controls ++(180:1/4) and ++(  0:1/8) .. cycle;
\fill [MaterialRed800] (0, -1)
  .. controls ++(  0:1/2) and ++(270:1/2) .. (   1,  0)
  .. controls ++( 90:1/2) and ++(  0:1/3) .. ( 1/3,  1)
  .. controls ++(180:1/4) and ++(  0:1/8) .. (   0,19/20) -- cycle;
\fill [MaterialRed900] (0,3/4) coordinate (@\i) 
  ellipse [x radius=1/4, y radius=1/8];
}
\fill [MaterialBrown]
  (1/4,11/8) -- (3/8,11/8) coordinate (@)
  .. controls ++(270:1/2) and ++(135:1/3) .. (@1)
  .. controls ++(135:1/2) and ++(270:1/2) .. cycle;
\fill [MaterialBrown]
  (1/4,11/8) -- (3/8,11/8)
  .. controls ++(315:1/2) and ++(45:1/2) .. (@2)
  .. controls ++(60:1/2) and ++(315:1/2) .. cycle;
\fill [MaterialGreen500, shift={(@)}, rotate=20] 
  (0,0) arc (45:135:3/4 and 3/5) arc (225:315:3/4 and 3/5);
\fill [MaterialGreen700, shift={(@)}, rotate=20] 
  (0,0) arc (315:225:3/4 and 3/5) -- cycle;
}}
\begin{document}
\tikz\foreach \i [evaluate={\j=int(mod(\i, 4));}] in {0,...,11}
  \path  (\i*30:5) 
    \ifcase\j pic {apple} \or pic {orange} 
          \or pic {lemon} \or pic {cherry}\fi;
\end{document}
```

[image: k]

Comment: You should say that this code actually comes from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413389/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-of-an-apple-using-only-the-tikz-library/413395#413395

Comment: @NaveganTEX I wish there was one. However, when you dont cross-refer the code, you are basically showing something as you made. However, in reality, it was created by someone else. Nevertheless, it's a nice gesture to let others know whose code you are using.

Comment: The trouble is that, now openclipart.org has gone, the availability of free fake fruit for conversion is inevitably somewhat thinner on the ground.  TeX SE is a less colourful place now its gone. (Though Mark Wilbrow scarcely needs it, I grant you.)

Answer (score 14):

#### A strawberry.

(Just for fun :)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{seed/.pic={\draw[red,thick] (0,0) .. controls (-0.2,0.8) and (0.2,0.8) .. (0.3,0.2) ..controls (0.4,-0.6) and (0.2,-0.5).. cycle;},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red,line width=1mm,fill=red!30] 
(3,9.5)node{X} 
.. controls (2.0,9.3) and (1.0,8.9) .. (0.5,7.0)
.. controls (0.2,5.0) and (0.2,3.0) .. (0.4,1.8)
.. controls (0.7,0.3) and (1.4,0.3) .. (2.0,0.2)
.. controls (3.0,0.3) and (4.0,0.6) .. (5.0,1.3)
.. controls (8.4,3.0) and (8.4,4.0) .. (8.2,5.4) 
.. controls (7.5,8.5) and (5.5,9.9) .. cycle;

\draw pic at (1,3) {seed}
pic[rotate=-10] at (1.0,5.5) {seed}
pic[rotate=-30] at (1.5,1.5) {seed}
pic[rotate=-45] at (1.8,8.2) {seed}
pic[rotate=-25] at (2.6,3.8) {seed}
pic[rotate=-40] at (2.5,6) {seed}
pic[rotate=-60] at (3,1) {seed}
pic[rotate=-55] at (3.3,2.4) {seed}
pic[rotate=-34] at (3.7,8) {seed}
pic[rotate=-45] at (4.2,2) {seed}
pic[rotate=-51] at (4.5,6) {seed}
pic[rotate=-22] at (5.5,3.3) {seed}
pic[rotate=-45] at (5.4,4.5) {seed}
pic[rotate=-45] at (4.5,4.6) {seed}
pic[rotate=-10] at (7,3.9) {seed}
pic[rotate=5] at (7.5,5.3) {seed}
;

\draw[green!50!black,line width=0.7mm,fill=green] 
(7.7,10.7) 
.. controls (7.5,10) and (7.5,9.5) .. (6.6,8.7)
.. controls (6.2,9.6) and (5.0,10.6) .. (4.5,10.5)
.. controls (4.6,10.2) and (4.7,9.9) .. (4.8,9.7) 
.. controls (4.5,9.8) and (3,9.8) .. (2.4,9.7) 
.. controls (4.2,9.4) and (4.6,8.9) .. (4.9,8.7)
.. controls (4,7.7) and (4,7) .. (4.2,6.8) 
.. controls (4.5,6.8) and (5,7.0) .. (6.0,7.0) 
.. controls (6.0,6.0) and (5.8,5.2) .. (5.6,4.9) 
.. controls (7,5) and (7.5,6.1) .. (7.5,6.1) 
.. controls (8.1,5.6) and (8.2,5.1) .. (8.3,5.0) 
.. controls (8.8,5.7) and (8.3,6.5) .. (8.1,6.7) 
.. controls (8.5,6.8) and (8.7,6.8) .. (9.0,6.7) 
.. controls (8.8,7.6) and (7.9,8.2) .. (7.5,8.3) 
.. controls (7.7,8.5) and (8.4,9.0) .. (8.8,9.3) 
.. controls (9.0,10.5) and (8,11) .. cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Grapes

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{grapecolor}{rgb}{0.44,0.18,0.66}
\definecolor{leafcolor}{rgb}{0,0.7,0}
\tikzset{
grape/.pic={\draw[black,line width=0.7mm,fill=grapecolor, opacity=1.0] (0,0) circle (0.8);},
leaf/.pic={
\draw[line width=0.7mm,fill=leafcolor] (-0.1,0) 
.. controls (0.2,0.3).. (0.7,0.4)
.. controls (0.6,0.6) .. (0.5,0.75)
.. controls (1,0.7) .. (1.4,0.5)
.. controls (1.4,0.6) .. (1.35,0.9)
.. controls (1.5,0.9) and (2.5,0.9) .. (2.5,0)
.. controls (2.5,-0.9) and (1.5,-0.9) .. (1.35,-0.9)
.. controls (1.4,-0.6) .. (1.4,-0.5)
.. controls (1.0,-0.7) .. (0.5,-0.75)
.. controls (0.6,-0.6) .. (0.7,-0.4)
.. controls (0.2,-0.3) .. cycle;
\draw[black,line width=0.7mm] (0.2,0) -- ++(2.3,0)
(2.1,0) ..controls (2.0,0.3).. (1.6,0.6)
(2.1,0) ..controls (2.0,-0.3).. (1.6,-0.6)
(1.3,0) ..controls (1.2,0.2).. (0.9,0.4)
(1.3,0) ..controls (1.2,-0.2).. (0.9,-0.4);}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw pic[rotate=124] at (7,5.5) {leaf};
\draw[line width=1mm] (5,6.0) ..controls(5.6,7.3)..(5.7,8.5);
\draw
pic[rotate=-55] at (4.6,6.4) {grape}
pic[rotate=-10] at (3.4,3.8) {grape}
pic[rotate=-30] at (3.3,5.1) {grape}
pic[rotate=-45] at (4.7,4.3) {grape}
pic[rotate=-25] at (4.6,5.6) {grape}
pic[rotate=-40] at (3.4,6.5) {grape}
pic[rotate=-60] at (5.8,5.0) {grape}
pic[rotate=-55] at (5.8,6.1) {grape}
;
\draw pic[rotate=-4] at (3,7.5) {leaf};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Grapes again

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{grapecolora}{rgb}{0.44,0.18,0.66}
\definecolor{grapecolorb}{rgb}{0.33,0.12,0.44}
\definecolor{leafcolor}{rgb}{0,0.7,0}
\tikzset{
grape/.pic={\fill[grapecolorb] (0,0) circle (0.8);
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,-0.8) rectangle (0.8,0.8);
\fill[grapecolora] (0,0) circle (0.8);
\end{scope}
},
leaf/.pic={
\fill[leafcolor] (-0.1,0) 
.. controls (0.2,0.3).. (0.7,0.4)
.. controls (0.6,0.6) .. (0.5,0.75)
.. controls (1,0.7) .. (1.4,0.5)
.. controls (1.4,0.6) .. (1.35,0.9)
.. controls (1.5,0.9) and (2.5,0.9) .. (2.5,0)--cycle;

\fill[green] (2.5,0)
.. controls (2.5,-0.9) and (1.5,-0.9) .. (1.35,-0.9)
.. controls (1.4,-0.6) .. (1.4,-0.5)
.. controls (1.0,-0.7) .. (0.5,-0.75)
.. controls (0.6,-0.6) .. (0.7,-0.4)
.. controls (0.2,-0.3) .. (-0.1,0)--cycle;
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw pic[rotate=124] at (7,5.5) {leaf};
\draw[line width=1mm] (5,6.0) ..controls(5.6,7.3)..(5.7,8.5);
\draw
pic[rotate=-45] at (4.6,6.4) {grape}
pic[rotate=-45] at (3.4,3.8) {grape}
pic[rotate=-45] at (3.3,5.1) {grape}
pic[rotate=-45] at (4.7,4.3) {grape}
pic[rotate=-45] at (4.6,5.6) {grape}
pic[rotate=-45] at (3.4,6.5) {grape}
pic[rotate=-45] at (5.8,5.0) {grape}
pic[rotate=-45] at (5.8,6.1) {grape}
;
\draw pic[rotate=-4] at (3,7.5) {leaf};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You nailed it! Looks fantastic!!!

Comment: +1, Although a strawberry is much redder.

Comment: @AndréC This one just isn't ripe yet. Sadly, it was picked too soon and will never now attain full red-bodied strawberry-hood.

Comment: @cfr A strawberry that is not ripe is never pink. It is white with red parts.

Comment: @AndréC Generally, but there are sometimes pink bits, too. (And green, for that matter.) But I do agree I've never seen one uniformly pink.

Comment: The existing fruits have some kind of shade and no border. Do you think you could design yours similarly, so that they better fit the others? =)

Comment: @JasperHabicht Tried for grapes, See the modfied answer.

Comment: @nidhin awesome!