# Strange behaviour involving nested TikZ pics an the to path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I have become quite fond of using TikZ pics, but sometimes I run into some unexpected behaviour.

As far as I know, if you define coordinates like `(-A)`, `(-B)`,... inside a pic and draw the pic later as `\pic (yourname) {pictype};`, you can access them as `(yourname-A)`, `(yourname-B)`, and so on, which is quite convenient if you want to build a base/scaffolding pic on which you add more stuff in subsequent pics.
But sometimes this breaks in unexpected ways:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        brokenbase/.pic={
            \node (-A) at (0,0) {};
            \draw (-A) to[in=0] (0,0);
        },
        broken/.pic={
            \pic (B) {brokenbase};
        },
        works/.pic={
            \node (-A) at (0,0) {};
            \draw (-A) to (0,0);
        },
        worksbase/.pic={
            \pic (B) {worksbase};
        }
    }
    \tikz{\pic {works};}
    \tikz{\pic {broken};}
\end{document}
```

I've implemented the same thing twice here: A base pic that draws an empty node and then a `to`-path from the node to the origin. If I don't give any arguments to the `to`-path, this works. If I give an `in` or `out` argument, it fails with this error:
`Package pgf Error: No shape named BB-A is known.`

I have heard of a similar bug here: [TikZ: Named nodes in nested `pic`s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176900/tikz-named-nodes-in-nested-pics)
But I don't think my problem is exactly the same since it goes away once you don't give `to` any options or use a usual `--` path.

P.S.: It seems it would make some sense to have "pic inheritance" in an OOP sense. Anyone up to implement that? ;)

Comment: Switch the name `broken` and `brokenbase` in the pic definition should make the problem go away.

Comment: Something strange is happening here. If you add [alias=BB-A] to the node in `pic{brokenbase}` it works. This looks like a bug in node naming of pics.

Comment: @Jesse yes, if you don't use nasted pics it works. But the problem is with naming nodes in nested pics.

Comment: The `to` operation needs to know the name of the nodes to link (to define `\tikztostart` and `\tikztotarget`). So this bug is the same as the linked question.

Comment: In my case, I can get away with giving the base pic an empty name: `\pic () {brokenbase};`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit, but why does `to` without arguments not need to know? Because it just invokes `--`?

Comment: @Turion It is almost that. But a full explanation would not fit in a comment (in fact, with `to`, the bug only occurs with a named `\tikztostart` node: in your example, if you permute `(-A)` and `(0,0)`, all is fine.)